# How to deploy more than one application to single Gitlab managed cluster?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I saw projects hosted on Gitlab with Gitlab AutoDevOps connect to a separate GKE cluster, with every project connecting to its own GKE cluster.

I saw there is something called monorepo in Gitlab which can be used to deploy everything on a single cluster but clusters being expensive to create for a single project, what was the reason behind Gitlab going for one cluster per project instead of say, one namespace per project or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> instead of say, one namespace per project or something else?

Actually... [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#customizable-namespaces-for-gitlab-managed-clusters) (October 2020) has now:

> ### Customizable namespaces for GitLab Managed Clusters
>
> Users of GitLab Managed Clusters can **now choose to use a single namespace per project, or a single namespace per environment, when creating clusters**.
>
> While single namespaces per project simplified finding review apps, separate namespaces per environment can provide additional security.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/add_remove_clusters.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/38054).